# Debian/Ubuntu, inconsistency between S-ATA ports numbering and /dev/sdX lettering

Tags: diskmanagement, udev, drive, dev

The hardware situation is as such :

- a motherboard (MSI X99A SLI Plus),
- two (2) Samsung 860 Pro SSDs connected on SATA-1 and SATA-2 of the motherboard.
- five (5) identical HDDs connected on SATA-3, SATA-4, SATA-5, SATA-6, SATA-7

The BIOS correctly sees two SSDs on the two first SATA port, and all following HDD on following port.

**Issue** :
Debian, Ubuntu, and Proxmox see one of the HDDs first as `sda`, then the two SSDs `sdb` and `sdc`, and then the HDDs again as `sdd`, `sde`, `sdf`, `sdg`

**Expected** :
The SSD connected to SATA-1 and SATA-2 as `sda` and `sdb`. Then all the HDDs on the following letters.

I would like to get the expected behavior, for ease of understanding/maintenance.

[image: What the bios sees]

[image: What a debian based OS sees]

Answer (score 1):

SATA ports have no influence on what /dev/sdX they get. The Linux kernel assigns the letters based on what is detected first. When mounting drives etc it’s much safer and easier to use the UUID of the drive as it is persistent

Comment: According to this accepted answer https://superuser.com/questions/940060/which-sata-port-is-my-disk-connected-to the port numbers on the motherboard *should* correspond to the sdX letter.
As stated in the original question, the behavior is expected for clarity's sake. I am not planning on manually using /dev/sdX for anything but clarity as the machine is a Proxmox node.

Comment: Let’s put this a different way. If I have one drive and have it in sata port 3... I wouldn’t get /dev/sdc

Comment: Alright, my OCD will have to settle for un-ordered list of drives. Thanks.